# How to show test report generated by mocha in bamboo

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, mocha.js, bamboo

I have node.js project and I'd like to run test cases written mocha (visionmedia.github.io/mocha/) in our bamboo (atlassian product), but mocha does not provide any reported for bamboo, ie. JUnit reporter.

I'm thinking about coverting xUnit to JUnit formart, but so far I've not found any solution for this.

Can any one advice?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Bamboo, but this link seems relevant: https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/pull/349

Comment: junit is not still "officialy" supported. the pull request was closed some time ago without any result.

Comment: I think TAP module will save me in near future https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-10955

Answer (score 1):

so far I fixed this by subunit combo:

```
mocha -R tap ./test/*.js > ./test-reports/result.tap

cd ./test-reports

cat ./result.tap | \
  tap2subunit | subunit2junitxml > result.junit && \
  xmllint --pretty 1 result.junit > result.junit.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

use https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-bamboo-reporter
there is a task "Mocha Test Parser" which is installed when you install the nodejs bamboo plugin.

Pickup the results written from the mocha-bamboo-reporter with this task in "final tasks" of your build stage